# error when trying to load typescript-written package into react storybook project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, storybook, react-native-web

im working on storybook tests for my react-native project
I decided to use `react-native-web` to run storybook as a website
Everything is running fine.
Until im trying to run test for some component that uses `react-native-inappbrowser-reborn` package.
Im getting this error:

[image]

As far as i can see - the error is because `inappbrowser-reborn` uses this syntax:
[image]

here is my storybook/main.js file:

```
  module.exports = {
    stories: ["../storybook/stories/**/*.stories.js"],
    addons: [
      "@storybook/addon-actions",
      "@storybook/addon-knobs",
      "@storybook/addon-docs",
      "storybook-addon-rtl",
    ],
    webpackFinal: async (config) => {
      config.resolve.alias = {
        ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
        // Transform all direct `react-native` imports to `react-native-web`
        "react-native$": "react-native-web",
        // make sure we're rendering output using **web** Storybook not react-native
        "@storybook/react-native": "@storybook/react",
        // plugin-level react-native-web extensions
        "react-native-svg": "react-native-svg/lib/commonjs/ReactNativeSVG.web",

        // ...
      };

      // handle SVG support inside Storybook
      const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) =>
        rule.test.test(".svg")
      );
      fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/;
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: "svg-react-loader",
      });

      // mutate babel-loader
      config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.plugins.push([
        "react-native-web",
        { commonjs: true },
        //,
      ]);

      return config;
    },
  };
```

Please help!

Comment: I have a different, but related issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: not yet, i just fingured out how to avoid build a sb test with the package... sorry